# Свойство crop, которое подгоняет фото под размер рамки

Tags: css, вёрстка

Кто-нибудь знает свойство `crop`, которое подгоняет фото под размер рамки и какие у него атрибуты, просто я слышал, но в справочниках не нашёл?

Comment: @kff, clip вроде не в тему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```
object-fit: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

В примере специально поставил высоту блока меньше ширины при том, что изображение горизонтальное. Вырезается часть изображения и полностью покрывает весь блок.

Поиграйте размерами блока, увидите.

```css
.photo_frame {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px blue solid;
}

.photo_frame img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo_frame">
  <img src="http://profismart.org/album/02/Priroda_144.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Вот так вспомнил o_O...

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего, вы имели ввиду свойство `object-fit: cover`. Однако дело в том, что это свойство не работает в IE и Edge. Поэтому посоветую вам задать картинку фоном и использовать свойство `background-size: cover`. Пример:

```css
.background {
  background: url("http://1000.tech/img/bg0.jpg") no-repeat 50% / cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: а что, если нужно сделать не где-нибудь на сайте, а в меню, где картинка выбирается из бд с помощью php, как в этом коде

Comment: <code> <div class="image-block">     
     <!--<a title="<?php //echo $product->product_name ?>" href="<?php //echo $product->link.$ItemidStr; ?>">
      <?php //echo $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage"', false); ?>      
     </a> -->
     <?php if(count($product->images)== 1) : ?>
     <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $pLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $pName; ?>">
      <span class="pro-image first-image">
       <img class="browseProductImage" src="<?php echo $pImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $pName; ?>" title="<?php echo $pName; ?>" />
      </code>

Comment: <code> <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if(count($product->images)>= 2) : ?>
     <a class="product-image2" href="<?php echo $pLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $pName; ?>">
      <span class="pro-image first-image">
       <img class="browseProductImage" src="<?php echo $pImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $pName; ?>" title="<?php echo $pName; ?>" />
      </span>
      <span class="pro-image second-image">
       <img class="browseProductImage" src="<?php echo $pImage_second; ?>" alt="<?php echo $pName; ?>" title="<?php echo $pName; ?>" />
      </span> 
     </a>
     <?php endif; ?> 
</div> </code>

Answer (score 3):

`crop` нет, зато есть [`background-size`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size) со значением `cover`.